# CSS custom properties as fallback value of another one instead of fixed (predefined) value

Tags: css-variables

CSS Custom Properties allows fallback values in case of missing variable so, for example:

```
:root {
  --color1:red;
  --color2:blue;
}

body {
  background:var(--color1,gray);
  color:var(--foo,yellow);
}
```

will result in a `BODY` with *red* background color (because `--color1` does exist), but with yellow color for text because `--foo` custom properties does not exist.

It seems not possible to use a CSS custom properties also for the fallback value, so this code:

```
body {
  background:var(--color1,gray);
  color:var(--foo,--color2);
}
```

will not result in a *blue* text, but it will be used default browser color, tipically black one.

Why this behaviour?

Comment: because you always need `var()` when using CSS variables --> `color:var(--foo,var(--color2))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom properties or CSS variables are only accessed using the var() function.

Use `var(--my-var, var(--my-background, pink))`.

For more information, checkout out [Custom property fallback values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties).